# Swift 2 - protocol delegate not called

Tags: ios, delegates, swift2, protocols

I am trying to implement a `delegate` in order to call events in main viewController.

When I try to call the delegate in the `main view controller` I get the error:

> Instance member 'delegate' cannot be used on type 
>   'CustomPickerViewController'

What am I missing here?

IN my delegate file I have:

```
protocol CustomPickerViewControllerDelegate: class {
     func CustomPickerDidSelectRow(sender:CustomPickerViewController)
}

//MARK: The Main Class
public class CustomPickerViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

// DELEGATE
    weak var delegate: CustomPickerViewControllerDelegate?

override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        customPicker.delegate = self
        customPicker.dataSource = self

.....
    }

public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if component == 0 {

        }else {

        customLabel.text = arrayCustom[row]
        self.delegate?.CustomPickerDidSelectRow(self)
        }
    }


}
```

Main View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomPickerViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       CustomPickerViewController.delegate = self // ERROR

    }

func CustomPickerDidSelectRow(sender: CustomPickerViewController) {
        print("ok")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply assign like you did with the `CustomPickerViewController`. You need to create new object for that view controller and then assign the delegate,

**For eg :**

```
let customPickerVC = CustomPickerViewController()
customPickerVC.delegate = self
```

Comment: Thanks done this and I have added `viewController.presentViewController` now is working